# How I can change the default directory handler from dired to deer or ranger?

Tags: dired

How can I replace dired with something like deer?  Any time emacs wants to browse a directory with `C-x d` or from a link on the homescreen (from projectile or something), I want to open it in ranger or deer instead of dired.  Is that possible?

Comment: You want https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el#installation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the `find-directory-functions` variable.

By default (in most cases) it results in `dired-noselect` being used. You would add a function which used the thing you want to use instead, making sure it has priority over the dired entry (if not replacing it entirely; depending on your exact intentions).

Your function will be called (by `find-file-noselect`) with a parameter of the directory path.

For the specific dired bindings like `C-x d`, you would want to remap them to your preferred commands.

e.g.

```el
(global-set-key [remap dired] 'my-dired-replacement)
```

Comment: While this is a fine answer, it ignores that ranger is a ncurses program and deer a zsh-specific thing.

Comment: I confess that I was presuming these were Emacs libraries (or at minimum, things with existing Emacs integration). Perhaps the question was actually referring to https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el which also has a "Minimal Ranger Mode" named `deer-mode`?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `(ranger-override-dired-mode t)` in your init file. See https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el#setting-as-default-directory-handler